# Spring JPA Hibernate JPQL find index of item that was passed in where clause

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

Suppose I have an Entity

```
@Entity
class DummyEntity{
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private long id;

     @ElementCollection
     @CollectionTable(name = "my_integers", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "my_integers_id"))
     private List<Integer> listOfIntegers;

     //getters setters

}
```

Now I want to get if an integer was in DummyEntitys listOfInteger, so in `JpaRepository` i write

```
public interface DummyEntityRepository implements JpaRepository<DummyEntity, Long>{

      @Query(value = "SELECT d from DummyEntity where :i MEMBER OF d.listOfIntegers")
      List<DummyEntity> parentsOfI(@Param("i") int i);

}
```

Ok up to now, but now I want to find the index of `i` in `listOfIntegers`, How can I do that ? or If can I do that ?

Comment: I'm sure the only way is programmatically. Moreover, is a `List` not a `Set`. What would happen in the case there are repeated integer in the List?

Comment: happy to accept it as answer (could not find any other way than programatically), please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is programmatically.

Moreover, is a `List` not a `Set`.

What would happen in the case there are repeated integer in the List?